# Visual Studio Code for ARM

Tags: arm, atmel-studio, toolchain

I use Atmel ARM chips and I'm used to use Atmel Studio 7 for developing. I want to try a more elegant editor for developing and I like the Visual Studio Code (VSCode). It's very nice editor. But I don't know how to use it with ARM toolchain which Atmel Studio has.

Any hint about how I could get started with this?

Comment: If it is possible - there should be a bunch of tutorial around.

Comment: [Have you checked Microsoft's website?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635843.aspx)

Comment: Visual Studio Code is bascially a text editor. So of course you can use it to edit your source files, and then compile your code from the command-line with the ARM toolchain. Now, if you want to use it for debugging too, you can find extensions to make it work with gdb. Check "vscode gdb". I'm sure Google knows how to set this up.

Comment: @KingDuken the link you provided is for *Visual Studio* 2015, which is a completely different product from *Visual Studio **Code***. I know, it's confusing....

Comment: @dim Oh I see... Well in that case... MrBit just look into the Extension marketplace on the left side of the window and search for "Arm"... Literally the first thing you see.